# Calculate future date

Tags: date-time, date

I want to calculate a future date based on the date the post is published and use it in the content of a post.

I can echo the post publication date using:

```
echo the_date('Y-m-d');
```

How can I calculate the future date?

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$future_timestamp = strtotime('+1 week', get_the_date('Y-m-d'));

echo date('Y-m-d', $future_timestamp);
```

or

```
$future_timestamp = get_the_date('U') + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7);

echo date('Y-m-d', $future_timestamp);
```

Comment: One Trick Pony is my hero!  Just what I needed, wanted and can use.  Many, many thanks!

Comment: Then you should make his answer as accepted!